# wp_query: How to retrieve current term slug in custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Using the [WP Types Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/), I setup a custom post type (slug: `portfolio`), which has a custom taxonomy (slug: `portfolio-category`).

The custom taxonomy has three items (slugs: `group1`, `group2`, `group3`) to organize portfolio posts.

On each single portfolio page I am displaying 3 related posts from the same taxonomy term, filtered by slug:

```
global $post;

$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio-category', array("fields" => "names"));

      $wpex_port_query = new WP_Query(
          array(
              'post_type' => 'portfolio',
              'showposts' => '3',
              'orderby' => 'rand',
              'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
              'no_found_rows' => true,
              'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
                     'field'    => 'slug',
                     'terms'    => $term_list,
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

This basically works, but I am wondering if there is a better way than creating a global variable `$post`? What is the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your issue is precisely, you are not creating `$post`, just accessing it. It is a very common sight in WordPress.

However from API point of view, is ID of current post is the only thing you need — use [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) function to get just that, sans dealing with global yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_queried_object_id()` if for some reason the global `$post` doesn't currently contain the main query's post object, though `wp_reset_postdata()` should fix that if that's the case. As Rarst said, it's not really harmful to access the global `$post`, it already exists anyway.